# Como funciona la función fork()

Tags: proceso

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int pid;

    printf("PADRE: Soy el proceso padre y mi pid es: %d\n", getpid());

    pid = fork();

    // En cuanto llamamos a fork se crea un nuevo proceso. En el proceso
    // padre 'pid' contendrá el pid del proceso hijo. En el proceso hijo
    // 'pid' valdrá 0. Eso es lo que usamos para distinguir si el código
    // que se está ejecutando pertenece al padre o al hijo.

    if (pid) // Este es el proceso padre
    {
        printf("PADRE: Soy el proceso padre y mi pid sigue siendo: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("PADRE: Mi hijo tiene el pid: %d\n", pid);
    }
    else // Proceso hijo
    {
        printf("HIJO: Soy el proceso hijo y mi pid es: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("HIJO: mi padre tiene el pid: %d\n", getppid());
    }
}
```

Comment: Justo como el que escribiste. ¿Podrias decirnos expresamente que quieres conseguir? Si el único objetivo es crear un proceso, ya lo has completado.

Comment: O osea printf  sería el proceso ? Eso es lo ir aún no entiendo ese printf se puede cambiar por otras líneas de código que contenga un programa en cuestión

Comment: A ya, creo que la pregunta entonces sería ¿Como funciona la función fork() para crear procesos? La respuesta conllevaría varios puntos así que empezaré a elaborarla. Por lo mientras edita el nombre de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo primero que hay que saber es que todo programa en ejecución es un proceso.
Por ejemplo, el siguiente programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hola mundo, soy un proceso que solo imprime un mensaje\n");
}
```

Una vez que se compile y ejecute dicho programa  se volverá un proceso.
Dicho proceso será creado en la memoria principal con los datos necesarios para su ejecución como un apuntador a la instrucción a ejecutar, memoria para sus variables, etc...
Usando esos datos en memoria, el proceso finalmente será capaz de ejecutar las instrucciones que componen al programa (en este caso, solo un printf).

Todos los procesos son manejados por el sistema operativo, el cual los diferencia entre sí con un identificador único de proceso, o process id (pid).
El pid lo podemos consultar mediante la función getpid() de la cabecera unistd. Con dicha función podríamos hacer que nuestro programa imprima su propio identificador de proceso cuando se ejecute:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hola mundo, mi identificador de proceso es: %d\n", getpid());
}
```

Normalmente los procesos se inician al ejecutar los programas. Sin embargo, a veces surge la necesidad de que un proceso cree a su vez otro proceso independiente.
Ahí es cuando entra la función fork(), que en el momento en que es llamada crea un clon idéntico del proceso que la ejecutó.

Si, por ejemplo, usáramos la función (llamada al sistema) fork() en el programa anterior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    fork(); // En este punto el programa crea un clon de si mismo

    printf("Hola mundo, mi identificador de proceso es: %d\n", getpid());
}
```

Y ahora compilamos y ejecutamos este nuevo programa, veremos que en lugar de ver un solo mensaje de saludo, veremos dos mensajes distintos parecidos a lo que viene (Los números cambiarán en cada ejecución):

```
Hola mundo, mi identificador de proceso es: 4608
Hola mundo, mi identificador de proceso es: 4609
```

En un primer momento había solo un proceso que iba a imprimir un solo mensaje.  Sin embargo en el momento en que llamamos a fork(), dicho proceso creó un hijo idéntico a el, por lo que ahora tanto el proceso original como el nuevo imprimirán el mismo mensaje (o casi). La única diferencia entre los dos mensajes es el identificador de proceso, porque, a pesar de que ambos procesos sean clones, el sistema operativo aún debe poder diferenciar entre ellos y por ende usa un pid distinto para cada uno.

Sin embargo, generalmente no tiene sentido crear un proceso que haga lo mismo que el padre. La gran mayoría de las veces lo que querremos es que el nuevo proceso realice una tarea distinta a su creador. Entonces, ¿Es posible hacer que dos procesos no sean clones idénticos para que cada uno realice una tarea distinta? Respuesta corta: no.

Y justamente ese es el mayor problema al que nos vamos a enfrentar al hacer uso de la función fork(). Tenemos que arreglárnoslas para que mediante un mismo código, dos procesos hagan cosas distintas. La forma de afrontar dicho problema es justamente la que se usa en el código de tu pregunta: Por medio de if ambos procesos comprobarán si son el proceso hijo o son el proceso padre.  ¿Cómo se realiza dicha comprobación? Pues por medio de la única cosa diferenciable entre los dos procesos: su pid.

Para entender dicho if hay que saber un par de cosas sobre la función fork():
    - Dicha función va a regresar un valor tanto al proceso original (padre) como al nuevo proceso
      (hijo)
    - Al proceso padre le va a regresar el pid de su hijo. Al proceso hijo le va a regresar 0.

Sabiendo esto, nos podemos plantear que la estructura general para manejar procesos es la siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid = fork();

    // instrucciones que tanto el padre como el hijo harán

    if (pid != 0)
    {
        // instrucciones que solo el proceso padre hará
    }
    else
    {
        // instrucciones que solo el proceso hijo hará
    }
}
```

De esta forma, aunque ambos procesos tengan el mismo código, cada uno seguirá una serie de instrucciones distintas.

Básicamente eso sería todo lo que hace falta para saber manejar múltiples procesos con un solo código. La única anotación que faltaría es que getppid() es una función que te regresa el pid del padre. getppid() puede usarse en cualquier proceso aunque no se haya hecho uso de fork() dado que todos los procesos excepto el primero de todos (usualmente llamado init o systemd) tienen un padre.